# Socket.io: emit no event

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I try to emit event "player move" with a json-object:

```
    this.broadcast.emit("player move", JSON.stringify(player));
```

but on the client I get this:

```
INFO: > 5:::{"args":[{"x":108,"y":105}],"name":"player move"}
```

Which doesnt show an event. Why is this? (This is from a socket.io framework in JavaScript).

Im using socket.io 0.9.17

EDIT: More code

```
client.on('player move', onPlayerMove);
```

Then the function:

```
function onPlayerMove(data) {
var player = playerWithId(this.id);
if (!player) {
    util.log("Player not found: " + this.id);
    return;
}
player.setX(data.x);
player.setY(data.y);


this.broadcast.emit("player move", JSON.stringify(player));
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaking, you should have apostrophes at the first curly bracket and the one directly after the square bracket, which makes a difference between JSON objects and JavaScript objects.
Example:

`var text = '{ "employees" : [' +
'{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" } ]}';`

Reference: [JSON Howto - W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp)

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: Well I use JSON.stringify() so I think the formatting is fine.

Comment: Then, if possible, could you provide more code (on the client- and the server-side)? Thanks!